# How to fix the position of a geom_text with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a chart like this one.

[image]

But I get something like this one.

[image]

This is my data frame.

```
 dput(mydata4)
structure(list(원격.수업.방식 = c("A", "A", "A/B", "A/B", "A/B/C", 
"A/B/C", "A/C", "A/C", "B", "B", "B/C", "B/C", "C", "C"), name = c("학업.기여도.x", 
"학업.기여도.y", "학업.기여도.x", "학업.기여도.y", "학업.기여도.x", 
"학업.기여도.y", "학업.기여도.x", "학업.기여도.y", "학업.기여도.x", 
"학업.기여도.y", "학업.기여도.x", "학업.기여도.y", "학업.기여도.x", 
"학업.기여도.y"), value = c(1.955, 1.121, 2.25, 1.035, 2.5, 1.179, 
3, 1.414, 2.718, 1.324, 2.75, 0.957, 2.727, 1.302)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is code that I used.

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(tidyverse)

mydata4 <- mydata4 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(학업.기여도.x, 학업.기여도.y), names_to = 'name', values_to = 'value')

mydata4
# A tibble: 14 x 3

ggplot(data=mydata4) + geom_col(aes(x=원격.수업.방식, y = value, fill=name), position="dodge") + ggtitle("원격 수업 방식 별 학업기여도(평균/표준편차)") +theme(plot.title = element_text( face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20, color = "black")) + geom_text(aes(x=원격.수업.방식, y=value ,label=value) , position = position_dodge(.9))
```

When I used this,

```
   geom_text(aes(x=원격.수업.방식, y=value ,label=value) , position = position_dodge(.9), vjust=0.2, hjust=0.2)
```

[[image] [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8gsI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant reproduce the example but by looking at your code and plot. I guess all you need is a small adjustment in the vertical and horizontal direction. Just add two arguments to `geom_text` (Refer below)

```
geom_text(aes(x=원격.수업.방식, y=value ,label=value) , position = position_dodge(.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

I am not sure of the result. If its coming differently you can experiment yourself by changing the values of `vjust` and `hjust` argument in `geom_text`. It basically shifts the text along vertical and horizontal axis.

(Edited) Try below

```
  attach(mydata4)
  ggplot(mydata4) + 
  aes(x=원격.수업.방식, y = value, fill=name) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') + 
  ggtitle("원격 수업 방식 별 학업기여도(평균/표준편차)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text( face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 20, color = "black")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

Comment: I added the result of advice that you gave me. I want to make labels for red one on its center, and the other labels for blue one on its center.

Comment: Still my labels are biased. When Blue one's labels are in the middle of graph, Red one's labels are not in the middle of graph.

Comment: @JayChoi I have used `geom_bar()` instead of `geom_col()`. Let me know if it helps.